# "Background" VS "Record"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Could anyone please let me know whether in the following example we can substitute **"records"** for **"background"** without any change in meaning in idiomatic English:

> I had a job interview yesterday and at the beginning of the meeting, the interviewer told me: "Tell me about your **background**."

I think although these two words are used interchangeably in many cases (e.g. employment records / background,) using "record" here is a little odd-sounding, however I cannot explain the reason.

Please kindly help me to clear my doubt up.

Comment: The usage of the word 'records' would be ambiguous here, since it is not sure which records they want to hear about, employment records, sports records, educational records, etc. 'Background' would specify a more general and open-minded case.

Comment: If they ask about your _background_, they want you to talk about what you have done in the past that makes you interested in, and suitable for, the job. _Records_ has the specific meaning of written evidence, for example examination certificates. It would certainly change the meaning.

Comment: Interesting! Does your explanation apply to "employment records / background" and "education records / background" too @Kate Bunting?

Comment: I don't see the difference. Your background includes education, qualifications and any previous employment. Your records are the evidence of these, which you would _show_ rather than talk about.

Comment: Therefore (employment / education) record = (employment / education) evidence = (employment / education) documents. Also, the choice "background" works far better here, as the interviewer has asked the interviewee for some verbal acknowledgments. Do you agree @Kate Bunting.

Comment: The interviewee has been asked to talk about him/herself - it's as simple as that.